# Spelling a word with chemical elements in Rust

Tags: rust

I tried solving [this /r/dailyprogrammer challenge](https://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/5seexn/20170206_challenge_302_easy_spelling_with/) in Rust.

I'm a complete Rust beginner, and I'm sure I've made a lot of mistakes. I would be very thankful for any tips or help you might be able to provide.

Here are a couple of points that I found awkward/confusing:

- In `show_result`, what I basically wanted to do was something like

  ```
  symbols = spelling.map {|e| e.symbol}.join("")
  elements = spelling.map {|e| e.name}.join(", ")
  ```

  but that didn't seem to work.
- I'm not exactly sure why I have to clone the elements to put them into the result vector. Can I/should I avoid this?
- Coming from a dynamically typed garbage collected language, I had a hard time deciding when and where to use references.

Thank you very much!

```
extern crate csv;

use std::env;
use std::path::Path;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::option::Option;
use std::vec::Vec;

#[derive(Clone)]
struct Element {
    number: u16,
    symbol: String,
    name: String
}

impl Element { 
    fn new (number: u16, symbol: &str, name: &str) -> Element {
        Element { 
            number: number,
            symbol: symbol.to_string(),
            name: name.to_string()
        }
    }
}

// Read all elements from CSV file into a hash map
fn read_elements() -> HashMap<String, Element> {
    let mut elem_map = HashMap::new();

    let path = Path::new("./elements.csv");
    let mut csv_reader = csv::Reader::from_file(path).unwrap();
    for record in csv_reader.decode() {
        let (number, symbol, name): (u16, String, String) = record.unwrap();
        let symbol = symbol.trim();
        let name = name.trim();
        elem_map.insert(symbol.to_lowercase().to_string(), Element::new(number, symbol, name));
    };

    return elem_map;
}

// Try to spell target_word using elements from elem_map
fn spell_word(target_word: &str, elem_map: HashMap<String, Element>) -> Option<Vec<Element>> {
    let mut result: Vec<Element> = Vec::new();
    let target_word = target_word.to_lowercase().to_string();

    // How far we've matched so far
    let mut current: usize = 0;

    while current < target_word.len() {
        // Try matching the next two letters first
        if current + 2 <= target_word.len() {
            let next_two = &target_word[current..current + 2];
            if let Some(ref elem) = elem_map.get(next_two) {
                result.push((*elem).clone());
                current += 2;
                continue;
            }
        }

        // Try matching one letter if two letters failed
        let next_one = &target_word[current..current + 1];

        if let Some(ref elem) = elem_map.get(next_one) {
            result.push((*elem).clone());
        } else {
            // If no one letter element could be found,
            // this word cannot be spelled using elements
            return None;
        }
        current += 1;
    }

    return Some(result);
}

// Print the found spelling
// e.g. PoISON (polonium, iodine, sulfur, oxygen, nitrogen)
fn show_result(spelling: Vec<Element>) {
    let mut symbols: String = String::new();
    let mut elements: Vec<String> = Vec::new();

    for elem in spelling {
        symbols.push_str(&elem.symbol);
        elements.push(elem.name.to_lowercase());
    }

    println!("{} ({})", symbols, elements.join(", "));
}

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    let elements = read_elements();

    if args.len() <= 1 {
        println!("Please provide a word to spell.");
    } 

    let target_word: &str = &args[1];

    match spell_word(target_word, elements) {
        Some(spelling) => show_result(spelling),
        None => println!("Could not find a match for word \"{}\".", target_word)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Overall

1. Don't explicitly import `Vec` or `Option`, they are part of the prelude.
2. Basically always want to implement `Debug` on any type.
3. I see two types that aren't there: something that holds the elements, something that contains results.
4. This allows you to implement `Display` for `Spelling`. This is more flexible and participates in the ecosystem better.

#### `read_elements`

1. No need to use `Path` explicitly, `&str` implements `AsRef<Path>`.
2. Can `collect` iterator of tuples into a `HashMap`, no need to muck about with a mutable variable.
3. Don't use `unwrap`. Prefer `expect` or return a `Result`. `expect` has words that will help you or the user find the problem. Note that we can `collect` into a `Result`.
4. Don't hardcode the filename inside the function.

#### `spell_word`

1. Should not take `elem_map` by value. Take a reference as we aren't making use of the allocated data.
2. I'd split the string and just track the string pieces, not the distance into the string.
3. No explicit `return` at the end of function.
4. Return references to the element instead of cloning.

#### `show_result`

1. Don't specify the types on a variable binding; let inference take care of it.
2. Don't take ownership of `Vec`, instead take a slice.
3. I'd avoid allocating in the printing function. I used Itertools to help with the comma separating.

#### `main`

1. Don't specify the type of a collection, let inference take care of it (`let foo: Vec<_> = bar.collect()`).
2. Don't check for the argument and then implicitly check again (via indexing). A `match` or `unwrap` would be better.
3. No need to collect into a vector. Instead, skip the program name and just iterate over all the arguments - bonus feature!
4. No need to explicitly convert `String` to `&str`, a `&String` can be coerced to a `&str`.
5. Use raw strings to avoid escaping quotes

```
extern crate csv;
extern crate itertools;

use std::{env, fmt};
use std::collections::HashMap;

use itertools::Itertools;

type Error = Box<std::error::Error>;

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Element {
    number: u16,
    symbol: String,
    name: String
}

impl Element {
    fn new (number: u16, symbol: &str, name: &str) -> Element {
        Element {
            number: number,
            symbol: symbol.to_string(),
            name: name.to_string()
        }
    }
}

struct Elements {
    elem_map: HashMap<String, Element>
}

impl Elements {
    fn read_from_file(name: &str) -> Result<Self, Error> {
        let mut csv_reader = csv::Reader::from_file(name)?;

        let elem_map: Result<_, Error> = csv_reader.decode().map(|record| {
            let (number, symbol, name): (u16, String, String) = record?;
            let symbol = symbol.trim();
            let name = name.trim();
            Ok((symbol.to_lowercase().to_string(), Element::new(number, symbol, name)))
        }).collect();

        Ok(Elements { elem_map: elem_map? })
    }

    // Try to spell target_word using elements from elem_map
    fn spell_word(&self, target_word: &str) -> Option<Spelling> {
        let mut result = Vec::new();
        let target_word = target_word.to_lowercase().to_string();
        let mut target_word = target_word.as_str();

        while !target_word.is_empty() {
            // Try matching the next two letters first
            if target_word.len() >= 2 {
                let (head, tail) = target_word.split_at(2);

                if let Some(elem) = self.elem_map.get(head) {
                    result.push(elem);
                    target_word = tail;
                    continue;
                }
            }

            // Try matching one letter if two letters failed
            let (head, tail) = target_word.split_at(1);

            if let Some(elem) = self.elem_map.get(head) {
                result.push(elem);
                target_word = tail;
                continue
            }

            // If no one letter element could be found,
            // this word cannot be spelled using elements
            return None;
        }

        Some(Spelling(result))
    }
}

struct Spelling<'a>(Vec<&'a Element>);

impl<'a> fmt::Display for Spelling<'a> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        for elem in &self.0 {
            write!(f, "{}", elem.symbol)?;
        }

        write!(f, " (")?;

        for elem in self.0.iter().map(|e| e.name.as_str()).intersperse(", ") {
            write!(f, "{}", elem)?;
        }

        write!(f, ")")
    }
}

fn main() {
    let elements = Elements::read_from_file("./elements.csv").expect("Unable to read elements");

    for target_word in env::args().skip(1) {
        match elements.spell_word(&target_word) {
            Some(spelling) => println!("{}", spelling),
            None => println!(r#"Could not find a match for word "{}"."#, target_word)
        }
    }
}
```